# Check / Find Element based on id stored in global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a global variable named `nowPlaying` it stores id of certain posts in form of `post-32`, `post-48` ... How can achieve the following

```
Check if there is article with id = nowPlaying

if there is such article {
 //Do stuff
}
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
if ($('article#nowPlaying').length) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Comment: `if ($('article#nowPlaying').length > -1) { /* do stuff */ }` have u tried this? **Remember** you are checking length of id which should be unique in the page and should not be assigned to multiple elements in a single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a global var named `nowPlaying` that should be done this way:

```
if ($('article#'+nowPlaying).length) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Id must be unique, you can do simply:

```
if ($('#'+nowPlaying).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#'+nowPlaying).length)
```

try with this

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, `nowPlaying` is a variable which contains the article id, then you need to use the id selector with string concatenation

Also since ids should be unique in a document there is no need to use `article` in the selector

```
if ($('#' + nowPlaying).length)
```